# How to reduce size of image in laravel when upload?

Tags: php, laravel, image, upload, reduce

I want to reduce the image size on my e commerce site when I upload a picture.
which function should I add in this code below?

```
if (Input::hasFile('title_image')) {
    $Product = Input::file('title_image');
    Product->move(public_path() . '/../../products', $Product->getClientOriginalName() . ".png");
    $product->title_img = "products/" .$Product->getClientOriginalName() . ".png";
}
```